# Switch / case: case evaluated to true, not executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

I'm struggling with a switch case statement, which is evaluated as true.
Nevertheless, the code for that case statement is not being executed.
It's weird for me. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
switch ([operation, state]) {
        case [(Array((Number(state.result).toString() === ['']))) 
                && (Array((Number(state.secondNumber).toString() === ['']))) && 
                state.mathOp === '' && operation === '-'] :
                    console.log([operation, state]);
                    setState((state) => ({
                        result: -Math.abs(Number(['-'])),
                        mathOp: operation,
                        secondNumber: [""],
                    }));
                    setUpdatedState(false);
                    setValue(0);
                    break;
        
            default: 
                console.log(new Error('Unknown clickHandlerOp function error...'));
    }
```

Comment: `switch` uses strict comparison and any object which has not the same object reference is `false`. btw, why not use a simple `if` statement?

Comment: Hi nina, in the method is going to be a several conditions, so I thought that the best approach would be using a switch case statement. I will check carefully the object reference comparison. Anyway, if it won't work, then I will use a simple If statement. Thanks for your help!

Comment: what data do you have? btw, a small expression, like `Number(state.result).toString() === ['']` is always `false`, because any number is not equal to an array ...

Comment: Problem solved. By what I've seen, switch / case statement does not compare well between different object references. So yes, you have to use If statement. The problem you told me about comparing a number and an array is also true, I did have to cast the values to it's corresponding equal object to solve the problem. Thanks so much!